# Query a relationship in Laravel with WHERE method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called "User", which "belongsToMany" Items.
This relationship works fine, so I can easily do something like this:

```
User::find(4)->items->find(1)->name
```

Now, I would like to do something like this:

```
User::find(4)->items->where('name', '=', 'stick')->get()
```

I would expect the code to return all the user's items with the name "stick", but unfortunately that is not what happens. I receive this error:

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::where()"
```

I also tried to build a query scope:

```
public function scopeName($query, $name)
{
    return $query->whereName($name);
}
```

The query scope works when I do something like this:

```
Item::name('SC')->get()
```

but

```
User::find(4)->items->name('SC')->get()
```

still does not work.

Can you help me returning all the user's items, which have the name 'stick'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `items()` method, not use the magic property:

```
User::find(4)->items()->where('name', 'stick')->get();
//                  ^^
```

Comment: The documentation for this is located at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just get a single user's items named "stick", this is how you would do it:

```
$stickItems = Item::whereUserId(4)->whereName('stick')->get();
```

Here we are using Eloquent's [dynamic where methods](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_dynamicWhere), but you could rewrite it like so:

```
$stickItems = Item::where('user_id', '=', 4)->where('name', '=', 'stick')->get();
```

That should get you what you want.

Comment: Any mention of this in the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs) or API docs (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/) please?

Comment: @hoopyfrood: I added a link to the API docs where dynamic where method's are handled. :-)

Comment: Helpful Article ==> https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/dynamic-where-clauses-and-find-methods-in-eloquent-(laravel-4)